# Disable scrolling to the bottom of console in Intellij IDEA Rust plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, console, rust

Each time I build my application, the output in the console is scrolled to the bottom. The button forgets its state and I need to click it each time to see first error. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: There is an [issue](https://github.com/intellij-rust/intellij-rust/issues/1008) on GitHub for this. Unfortunately it doesn't look like there are any plans to fix it.

Comment: It does happen to me but for another environment: PyCharm on Linux Mint.